# ObjectStore in C#

Tags: c#

Is there an ObjectStore implmentation for csharp that allows be to generate string handles for my own objects, lookup these objects later on on from the string handle.
I can see there are implementations for C++, but in dotnet we have a garbage collector!
Lars

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (or more specifically for your case a `Dictionary<string, SomeObjectType>`)? Or more like [ObjectCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx)?

Comment: The poster may be referring to [ObjectStore OODBMS by Progress Software](http://web.progress.com/en/objectstore/)

Comment: @j.w.r, yes he might be, that's why I asked about precision.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't noticed ObjectCache before.

Comment: Cool ObjectStore in dotnet 4.0 is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

(I did not refer to the OO database from Progress)